# Look of surface plot {fields}

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm trying to customize the look of the surface of a thin plate spline plot in the package fields. For example:

```
require(fields)
fit<- Tps(ozone$x, ozone$y)
set.panel()
surface(fit, type="C", xlab=("East"), ylab=("North"))
```

How can I customize the axis so that I can get more tickmarks and labels?
Also, is there a way to overlay a grid corresponding to the tickmarks for both the X and Y axes?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `axes=F` to draw the plot without axes, then add them manually using `axis`.

For instance

```
surface(fit, type="C", xlab=("East"), ylab=("North"), axes=F)
# X axis every 5
axis(1, at=seq(-20, 30, 5))
# Y axis, at various points with custom labels. las=1 puts labels horizontally
axis(2, at=c(-20, -10, -5, 0, 20), labels=letters[1:5], las=1)
```

For the grid use the `grid` command for a regular grid or `abline` for an arbitrarily spaced one.

```
# 5x5 grid
grid(nx=5, ny=5, col="black", lty="dotted")
# Arbitrary gridlines
abline(v=seq(-20, 10, 5), h=seq(-10, 10, 2), col="gray")
```

Comment: @user2162727: note that you can use the same strategy with many of the plotting functions.